# I have removed the titlebar from my code but now i want the activity to be fullscreen, can someone suggest me how to do that in android studio?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fullscreen

My AndroidManifest.xml code is as follows :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.chintan.myapplication">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

My MainActivity.java code is as follows:

```
package com.example.chintan.myapplication;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

And my app looks something like this.. I want the "Armour" to be written at the top of the screen just below the notification bar.
[App looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jYL2v.png)

Comment: Post your AppTheme style

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1- create a FullScreenTheme inside styles.xml**

```
 <style name="FullScreenTheme" parent="your parent them"> // for example use this parent them --> Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
</style>
```

**2- add the theme in the menefist**

```
 <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:theme="@style/FullScreenTheme">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
    // Make fullscreen
    int UI_OPTIONS = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION;
    getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(UI_OPTIONS);
```

I use it to make my apps fullscreen and it works really well. It hides the nav bar and will only appear when you swipe upwards near the bottom of your device's screen

Answer (score 0):

Use this simple function and get rid of all problems

```
public void setFullscreen(boolean fullscreen) {
    WindowManager.LayoutParams attrs = getWindow().getAttributes();
    if (fullscreen) {
        attrs.flags |= WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
        AdHelper.bannerAd.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else {
        attrs.flags &= ~WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
        if (AdHelper.isBannerLoaded)
            AdHelper.bannerAd.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    getWindow().setAttributes(attrs);
}
```

Just Pass the parameters to `true` for fullscreen and `false` for exit fullscreen. That's it.

Answer (score 0):

Change your AppTheme as following

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

As I can see your app image you did not remove actionbar from your app theme.
Use **Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar** theme for not action bar. Then if you want action bar in any activity of your app then use **ToolBar** .

```
 <!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

</style>
```

Hope this will help you.